# Web-API JSON Parent Object Name

Tags: json, backbone.js, asp.net-web-api

created an web api that outputs json, trying to use it with backbone.js pagination plugin to ouput the results to the  backbone.js infinite-paging plugin

this is my outputed json

```
 [{"id":1,"title":"test1""desc":"book1"},
    {"id":2,"title":"test2","desc":"book2"},
    {"id":3,"title":"test3", "desc":"book3"},
    {"id":4,"title":"test4","desc":"book4"},
    {"id":5,"title":"test5","desc":"book5"},
    {"id":6,"title":"test6","desc":"book6"}]
```

but i need to have the name of object included as the backbone.js paginator requires to return the response object.  think im almost there but cant seem to get it to show or work out how i add the object name  to it

```
{"object name:"[{"id":1,"title":"test1","desc":"book1"},   {"id":2,"title":"test2","desc":"book2"},
{"id":3,"title":"test3","desc":"book3"},
{"id":4,"title":"test4","desc":"book4"},
{"id":5,"title":"test5","desc":"book5"},
{"id":6,"title":"test6","desc":"book6"}]}
```

**my .net api web api looks like this**

```
namespace newslist
{
public class NewsController : ApiController
{
    List<News> Articles = new List<News>{
        new  News { id=1, title="test1", desc ="test1"},
        new  News { id=2, title="test2", desc ="test2"},
        new  News { id=3, title="test3", desc ="test3"},
        new  News { id=4, title="test4", desc ="test4"},
        new  News { id=5, title="test5", desc ="test5"},
        new  News { id=6, title="test6", desc ="test6"}

    };

    public List<News> GetAllLatestNews()
    {
        return Articles;
    }      

    public News GetNewsById(int id)
    {
        var News = Articles.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.id == id);
        if (News == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        return News;
    }

    public IEnumerable<News> GetNewsByCategory(string desc)
     {
        return Articles.Where(
            (p) => string.Equals(p.desc, desc,
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
      }
   }
}
```

**class file:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

  namespace newslist
  {
  public class News
  {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If JSON only is okay, this should give you what you want.

```
public class NewsController : ApiController
{
    List<News> Articles = new List<News>{
        new  News { id=1, title="test1", desc ="test1"},
        new  News { id=2, title="test2", desc ="test2"},
        new  News { id=3, title="test3", desc ="test3"},
        new  News { id=4, title="test4", desc ="test4"},
        new  News { id=5, title="test5", desc ="test5"},
        new  News { id=6, title="test6", desc ="test6"}

    };

    public HttpResponseMessage GetAllLatestNews()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { ObjectName = Articles});
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks you that worked greate exactly what i was trying to do